# How to change Jupyter kernel and conda environment from within Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, jupyterhub

Use Case:

The cluster at my University has a JupyterHub instance. I have my own conda environments I like to use. Is there a way, after my Jupyter notebook has launched, for me to specify a conda environment and kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You should **first zip** your conda environments and **upload them** to your jupyter instance inside Jupyterhub. After **unzipping** the environments open terminal.

**Execute these command** for each environment you want to be available as a kernel -

```
source activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

Change the name and display name as per requirement.